# I can't get network-manager to connect to a network

Tags: wifi, drivers, networking

Like I said, I don't know how to get the stock network manager to connect to a network. I am on a late 2010 MacBook Air, so I don't have an ethernet port. I need wifi to connect to the internet. Everything else is running fine and dandy.

I'd usually assign this to some problems with the drivers or the firmware. This being a MacBook makes it even more likely. However, the weird part is that I CAN connect to wifi with no problems at all if I use the terminal. Here are the commands I use:

```
    sudo service network-manager stop
    sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid <Enter SSID here>
    sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

This makes it all work perfectly. But the thing is, it's a pain in the ass to connect to any network with a password, and it also doesn't support automatic reconnecting or anything like that. I don't want to have to do this every time.

Here are some other things I've tried:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

This didn't help. It wasn't just a bad install.

I tried instaling WICD instead and seeing if that would work, but there were some things wrong with it. First, I couldn't get it into wingpanel. Second, it's as ugly as all hell. Third, it still wouldn't connect to a network. Seriously, it did the same thing the stock network manager did. Got stuck on "Obtaining IP Address".

I don't know what to do, guys. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.